# Make OneDrive be my default Documents, Desktop directories, etc

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I just had to wipe my drive and start over with Windows 10. I have a 365 subscription. Previously, OneDrive's version of Documents, Desktop, Pictures, etc. seemed to be my defaults. So in the Quick Access menu of windows, clicking them took me to the OneDrive version of that directory. And the icons next to the OneDrive section of this menu looked the same as the ones in the Quick Accesss section, instead of the generic yellow folders.

I'd like it to behave like that again, so when I create and save new documents in various apps, the default save location starts in OneDrive/Documents.

[image]

Comment: Just enable the backup of important PC folders from within `OneDrive -> Backup -> Manage backup`, if that isn't what you are looking for, [edit] your question

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly what I wanted, thank you! Post as an answer if you like.